# Can you retain number value across generated siblings with Emmet in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2, emmet

I have the following emmet line:

```
.lightbox-5-row*8>a[href="#"][rel="lightbox[a]"]*5>img[src="file_$$.jpg"]
```

Which produces the following structure 8 times:

```
<div class="lightbox-5-row">
    <a href="#" rel="lightbox[a]"><img src="file_01.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#" rel="lightbox[a]"><img src="file_02.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#" rel="lightbox[a]"><img src="file_03.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#" rel="lightbox[a]"><img src="file_04.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#" rel="lightbox[a]"><img src="file_05.jpg" alt=""></a>
</div>
```

What I would like to do is to be able to increment the numbers of the files in the sibling `.lightbox-5-row` elements like below:

```
<div class="lightbox-5-row">
    <a href="#" rel="lightbox[a]"><img src="file_01.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#" rel="lightbox[a]"><img src="file_02.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#" rel="lightbox[a]"><img src="file_03.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#" rel="lightbox[a]"><img src="file_04.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#" rel="lightbox[a]"><img src="file_05.jpg" alt=""></a>
</div>
<div class="lightbox-5-row">
    <a href="#" rel="lightbox[a]"><img src="file_06.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#" rel="lightbox[a]"><img src="file_07.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#" rel="lightbox[a]"><img src="file_08.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#" rel="lightbox[a]"><img src="file_09.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#" rel="lightbox[a]"><img src="file_10.jpg" alt=""></a>
</div>
<div class="lightbox-5-row">
    <a href="#" rel="lightbox[a]"><img src="file_11.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#" rel="lightbox[a]"><img src="file_12.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#" rel="lightbox[a]"><img src="file_13.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#" rel="lightbox[a]"><img src="file_14.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#" rel="lightbox[a]"><img src="file_15.jpg" alt=""></a>
</div>
```

and so on... Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Why was this downvoted? There's nothing wrong with the question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it’s not possible with current Emmet syntax

Comment: Thank you for your answer Sergey :). Is it something we will see in the future?

Comment: You can create a feature request here: https://github.com/emmetio/emmet/issues
I’ll take a look what I can do

Comment: Thanks Sergey, will do that this week :)

Comment: Any progress with this mate ?

Comment: No progress yet. Any changes will be posted in GitHub issues

Comment: The issue he filed: https://github.com/emmetio/emmet/issues/335